# "Проверено()мин нет"

Tags: пунктуация

Всем известна фраза "Проверено() мин нет". Но какой знак препинания должен стоять после "проверено"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь должно быть двоеточие по правилу бессоюзного сложного предложения. Имеется в виду: "Проверено и выяснено: мин нет". У Розенталя  много подобных примеров.